# Android: is LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(googleApiClient, requestIds) idempotent

Tags: android, android-geofence

Can I call LocationServices.GeofencingApi.removeGeofences(googleApiClient, requestIds) method multiple times? Will it throw error if I do it?

Comment: What's the API documentation say?

Comment: By the way, that interface is deprecated https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingApi